# Azure Identity Server Authentication

Tags: azure, docker, identityserver4

In Azure, I have a docker-compose file for my web app instance that creates the Angular front-end, an IdentityServer4 server for authenticating users, and an API that handles communication to a DB.

The container logs seem to suggest that everything in the docker-compose is running just fine, but when I attempt to reach the IdentityServer4 login page from the Angular front-end, I keep receiving this error in the Console:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED  :5000/.well-known/openid-configuration:1
```

and also...

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Network Error   core.js:1624
```

I have replaced all of the localhost:5000 instances(for ID Server) with https://myapp.azurewebsites.net:5000, which I thought would handle the transition to Azure, but I can't seem to get past the above errors.

Does anybody know what I could be doing wrong here? Or what I can do to fix this issue?

Comment: are you able to do http get `https://myapp.azurewebsites.net:5000/.well-known/openid-configuration`

Comment: No, it appears that the request to access that url isn't being made somewhere. That's what I'm having trouble figuring out. This worked fine locally, but something in Azure is making the request fail

Answer (score 0):

Goto database and update clients based tables where the will `localhost:5000` mentioned. Replace localhost with `myapp.azurewebsites.net`

Comment: Good suggestion, but localhost:5000 does not exist anywhere in my Identity Server database. Other instances of localhost:5004, 5002, etc. have been replaced with my azure site name